# How to create an exe file in an openjdk11 environment?

Tags: java

I want to make and distribute a GUI program made with Java as an EXE file. Recently, the Java version was changed to openjdk11 and the JAVA_HOME setup was completed. An attempt was made to convert a file to a program such as Launch4j, but the application failed with the error 1.6.0 Java runtime environment assigned. How do I convert a jar file to an exe file in an openjdk11 environment?

Comment: *"This application ignored a java runtime environment 1.6.0 error occurred although the jar file was attempted to change to a program such as Launch4j."* - That sentence makes no sense.  Please correct it.

Comment: You say _"An attempt was made to convert a file to a program such as Launch4j"_ so you are looking for solution in Launch4j? What are settings you are using with Launch4j.  Is the error you received from Launch4J or is this your application error?

Comment: Attempted to convert using the Launch4j program, but a runtime error occurred.